# File Exists in Java?

Tags: java, file

I trying to check whether a file exists at given directory location.

```
File seacrhFile = new File("D:/input", contract.conf);
if (seacrhFile.exists()) {
  returnFile = seacrhFile;
} else {
  System.out.println("No such file exists");
}
reutrn returnFile;
```

This is working in `D:/input` directory scenario, but if I Change the directory location to `src/test/resources/input` folder then I am getting `No such file exists`, eventhough the file exists.

Comment: change the dir location to src//test//resources//input  and see if it works

Comment: `src/test/resources/input` is a relative path. The JVM must be executing in the parent directory of `src` for this to work.

Comment: try something like this (new File(getClass().getResource("/src/test/resources/input")).toURI()); this should work. You might have to experiment with the file name.

Comment: Are you describing a unit test in a Maven project? I ask because the layout "src/test/resources" is commonly used in Maven.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have access to
 src/test/resources/input
you probably should use

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "src/test/resources/input"
```

because the system-property "user.dir" points to the projectlocation.

If you just use "src/test/resources/input" you will get your mentioned exception, because the File Object don't "start" at the project location. So you have to specify it manually.

Nevertheless it's better to use the getResource-Method to retrieve different resources within your project, because if you run your project with the jar-File you need to tweak around to get "user.dir" to work correctly.

Just a basic example for the Classloader:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("test/resources/input");
```

This returns an URL-Object, with this object you can get the File-Object using ...

```
URL filePath =  ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("test/resources/input");
File file = new File( filePath.toURI() );
```

Comment: The file layout suggests that Maven is possibly in use. If so, it's worth bearing in mind the various classloaders in use when the unit tests run. See http://acupof.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/got-question-other-day-about-how-to_5208.html for an explanation of why `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the src and try it again .